# Segmentation fault deleting a row from a matrix

Tags: c++

I tried to delete a row from a matrix, but I only get segmentation fault and I don't know what's wrong whith my code.

My code is:

```
void Matriz2D::DeleteRow(int delete_row)
{

    int new_size = total_rows-1;

    int **tmp = new int * [new_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < new_size; i++){
        tmp[i] = new int [size_cols];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++){
        if(i != delete_row){
            for(int j = 0; j < toal_cols; j++){
                tmp[i][j] = data[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++){
        delete [] data[i];
    }

    delete [] data;
    data = tmp;

    total_rows--;
}
```

Comment: Why -1 in `int new_size = total_rows-1;`?

Comment: @VTT it is a function of deleting a row from matrix

Comment: Because what I want it's to delete a row, so the final matrix has a row less

Comment: Then why are you accessing it like it has `total_rows` rows?

Comment: `tmp` is initialised with `total_rows - 1` elements.    The second set of loops assign `tmp[i][j]` for `i` equal to 0 through `total_rows - 1`.    That means it falls off the end - i.e. undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh, yes. I changed it for new size. Anyway, I'm still geting a segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you do not check the index of the rows after the deleted one

```
void Matriz2D::DeleteRow(int delete_row)
    {

        int new_size = total_rows-1;

        int **tmp = new int * [new_size];

        for(int i = 0; i < new_size; i++){
            tmp[i] = new int [size_cols];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++){
            if(i != delete_row){
                for(int j = 0; j < toal_cols; j++){
                    if (i < delete_row) {
                       tmp[i][j] = data[i][j];
                    } else {
                       tmp[i][j] = data[i-1][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++){
            delete [] data[i];
        }

        delete [] data;
        data = tmp;

        total_rows--;
    }
```